# Adding building steps in Qt .pro file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

From QtCreator "projects - Add Building Step", one can specify added building steps. For example, the following setting will echo out a message when the project is built.
[image: Custom process step]

The added building step actually appears in the corresponding .pro.user file:

```
<value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.ProcessStep.Arguments">hello. This is my custom process step.</value>
<value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.ProcessStep.Command">/usr/bin/echo</value>
```

My question is: is there a way adding the building step in the .pro file instead of using the GUI ("projects - Add Building Step") and actually adding settings to .pro.user file? (To me, the advantage is that .pro files can be easily batch-processed with shell scripts.)

I tried to put the step in the .pro file with QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS as

```
mystep.commands = echo 'hello. This is my custom process step'
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mystep
```

However, with `qmake; make` from command line, only the original building happens. Only after a further `make mystep`, the echo happens. In another words, `mystep` step does not happen with a normal `make` - maybe I am misunderstanding `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`?

Comment: Maybe try adding `PRE_TARGETDEPS += mystep`?

Comment: Tried 'qmake; make` with 'PRE_TARGETDEPS += mystep` coded in. It complains about `make: *** No rule to make target 'mystep', needed by` the original TARGET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you found an answer that works for you. I want to clarify the comment I made above, since I tried it and it worked fine for me. (And was much simpler looking than your solution.) I think the reason it didn't work for you was because I intended you to combine PRE_TARGETDEPS with the QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS you already had. This should be all you need.

```
mystep.commands = echo 'hello. This is my custom process step'
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mystep
PRE_TARGETDEPS += mystep
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Your answer is better than mine since yours is much simpler as you mentioned. And you were right about my mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for a while, I found a solution - use QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS.

```
# must use a variable as input
PHONY_DEPS = .
mystep.input = PHONY_DEPS
# use non-existing file here to execute every time
mystep.output = phony.txt
# the system call to the batch file
mystep.commands = echo 'hello. This is my custom process step'
# some name that displays during execution
mystep.name = running mystep...
# "no_link" tells qmake we don’t need to add the output to the object files for linking
# "no_clean" means there is no clean step for them.
# "target_predeps" tells qmake that the output of this needs to exist before we can do the rest of our compilation.
mystep.CONFIG += no_link no_clean target_predeps
# Add the compiler to the list of 'extra compilers'.
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += mystep
```

For my real application, which is more than just an echo, I will be specifying output/CONFIG differently.

Reference:

- [Discussions from forum.qt.io](https://forum.qt.io/topic/82256/can-i-specify-a-pre_build-step-in-my-pro-file/19)
- [Adding compilers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers)